# Symfony assteic resources not cached by the browser

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony, caching

I am using the assetic manager to serve my css and js files however the browser is loading them on every page request instead of caching them locally. I have checked the Last-Modified response header when fetching the css/js file and it is the same time as the request, which I assume is why it is returning the full file with a 200 response instead of a 304.

I am using the production environment with the following config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"

            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
```

How can I get Symfony to send the Last-Modified time of the created assetic file so that it is cached in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assetic or Symfony do not set any Last-Modified cache headers for any asset files. Assetic just generates any needed css/js files and modifies any link that uses them, but then they are served by the web server as any other static file. You should look into your web server configuration to find out how to set Last-Modified headers for static files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out to be a problem with Apache adding a 'gzip' suffix to the etag (http://serverfault.com/questions/636976/why-does-apache-send-200-ok-while-last-modified-matches-if-modified-since). Although disabling etags didn't work disabling gzip did.